# Google Play Purchase History

Tags: php, android, google-api, google-play-services, in-app-subscription

Our server uses the PHP SDK to validate subscription purchases.
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/get

Is it possible to view purchase history on the server side via the SDK, or some endpoint? Basically I'm looking for a way to get the subscription order number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no API or endpoint that you can call/use to retrieve subscriptions/purchases history for Google Play.

AFAIK, the expected procedure for this is for developers to keep track of the history on their end by storing and keeping track of the `orderId`s and `purchaseToken`s accordingly on their side.